# Closed form of the sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

I was messing around with this sieve, and I started thinking, could one find a closed form of such a sieve? And this sieve SCREAMED inclusion-exclusion principle. So after using this principle, I obtained the following:

Let $\mathcal P$ denote the set of all primes $\leq x$. Then we have |$\mathcal P$|=[$x$]-$\lfloor \frac{x}{p_1} \rfloor$-$\lfloor \frac{x}{p_2} \rfloor$+$\lfloor \frac{x}{p_1p_2} \rfloor$+..., and we continue until we have added up all possible products of the primes, and subtracted all of the $\lfloor \frac{x}{p_i} \rfloor$. (We must also have that the maximum prime in this sequence must not exceed $\sqrt x$).

Would this be a correct way for writing the sieve?

Comment: What do you mean by closed form of a sieve? Do you mean a closed form for the prime-counting function?

Comment: It is a bit odd to formulate the prime counting function in a way that needs you to know all the values of the primes you are trying to count. Even so, the method would work except that you want to subtract the number of multiples of primes excluding the prime itself, so should use $(\lfloor \frac{x}{p_i} \rfloor-1)$ for the first set of terms. Also, the number $1$ is not prime but also not divisible by any of the $p_i$, and therefore should also be excluded from the count separately.